# Eigenvalue question with Dirichlet and Neumann condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, elliptic-operators

$\Omega$  is a open  connect bounded  set  of $\mathbb R^n$.
\begin{align}
-\Delta u   &=  \lambda u  \\
u|_{\partial\Omega} &=0    \\
\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}\right|_{\partial\Omega}   &=0
\end{align}
Whether this question have non-trival solution ? I mean the $\lambda$ and $u$ are not constant.

Comment: Read about the Hopf boundary point lemma.

Comment: http://www.math.umd.edu/~yanir/742/742-13-15.pdf

Comment: Probably $\lambda$ is supposed to be constant after all.